# Bulk Insert Rails SQLite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have been struggling for a while to get bulk inserts to work in my Rails setup. I am getting the following error message.

**SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error:** INSERT INTO tokens (article_id,count,'origin','created_at','updated_at','token') VALUES (42,1,'Title','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','5'), (42,1,'Title','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','Companies'), (42,1,'Title','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','To'), (42,1,'Title','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','Watch'), (42,1,'Title','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','In'), (42,1,'Title','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','2013-06-24 11:54:31 +0400','Big Data')

When I paste the above SQL string into the **SQLite plugin** for Firefox and execute the query it works fine. So I think there should be an issue with how I am using this string in Rails.

I have the following setup.

- Ruby 2.0
- Rails 3.2.13
- sqlite3 1.3.7
- Ubuntu 12.04

Here is the method that does the bulk upload. It takes 2 arguments. 1 Hash that contains string tokens and numeric counts of each token. The second argument is just a string.

The method is called on an instance of the Article class. So self.id is just the article ID.

I also tried bulk upload through the **activerecord-import** gem and it failed as well with a similar error message regarding syntax.

```
def token_list(names,originvar)
  vec =[]

  names.each do |i, count|
    time = Time.now
    vec << "(#{self.id},#{count},'#{originvar}','#{time}','#{time}','#{i}')" 
  end

  raw_sql = "INSERT INTO tokens (article_id,count,'origin','created_at','updated_at','token') VALUES #{vec.join(", ")}"

  Token.connection.execute(raw_sql)
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Comment: (I know it's not *quite* a dupe because that question doesn't involve Rails, but the core question of SQLite syntax is the same, and OP shouldn't need help with the Rails bit once that's resolved.)

Comment: Also, ew ew ew ew ew! Your current code, if it were proper SQLite syntax, would be super-vulnerable to SQL injection (or, if you're not worried because this is an internal-only thing, super-vulnerable to bugs from lack of escaping). Consider building the query another way.

Comment: Thanks Matchu, I looked at that question previously and used it to formulate my query. As I said the SQL works when I execute the query outside Rails. So the issue is either in my code or the SQLite gem. Thanks for the sequrity heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use single quotes here:

```
  raw_sql = "..... VALUES #{vec.join(', ')}"
```